# Format 15-digit number PHP

Tags: php, numbers, substr, digits

I'm trying to format the following number from a json url.

```
1835488750000000
```

to

```
18,354,887
```

Here is my code

```
$json_url = $Api;
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$total = $data['value'];    

echo number_format(trim($total , 0));
```

It returns

```
1.83549E+15
```

I'm tying to format the value of totalbc from the api url

Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual code you've tried, so we can try it ourselves and see where you went wrong.

Comment: Have you tried with `trim` ? `number_format(trim(1835488750000000, 0));`. Given your output, your `substr` probably did not remove the trailing zeros. Please follow the advice given in the comment above so we can help you fix your original code if you want to keep substr.

Comment: It would be nice to know what the number represents, because the output doesn't need to have the same value as the input. That's a rare situation.

Comment: @IMSoP code included. Thank you

Comment: @NoahBoegli code included. Thank you

Comment: Your previous version of the question said that you'd already tried `substr` and `number_format`; your edited code doesn't show that, so how are we supposed to know where you went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could divide it by `1E8` and use `number_format`:

```php
number_format(1835488750000000/1E8);
```